# Deserialize class instance in C++

Tags: c++, serialization

This my *.h

```
class ip_file_handler {

   struct IPheader {
      unsigned short int ver :4;
      unsigned short int ihl :4;
      unsigned short int total_length;
      unsigned char tos;
      unsigned char ttl;
      unsigned char protocol;
      unsigned int checksum;
      unsigned short int identification;
      unsigned short int flag_offset;
      unsigned int ucSource;
      unsigned int ucDestination;
   };

   public:

   ip_file_handler(){}

   // func 1 (file to ip)
   static bool file_to_ip_packets(std::string input_file_name,
                                  std::string output_file_name,
                                  unsigned int source_ip,
                                  unsigned int destination_ip);

   private:

   IPheader ipInfo;
   list<string> data;
};
```

---

in *.cpp:

all data of file into myHandler.

this line write class to file:

```
ofstream outFile(output_file_name.c_str(), ios::out | ios::binary);
ip_file_handler myHandler;
outFile.write((char*) &myHandler,sizeof(ip_file_handler));
```

/* here the problem */
this line read class from file:

```
ip_file_handler tmp;
outFile2.read((char*) &tmp, sizeof(ip_file_handler));
```

now why can't read class from file!?
outFile is'nt empty!

Thank for all.
Adam

Comment: In general it is NOT safe to binary dump an object to a file and binary dump it back into memory. You need to add functions (or stream operators) to write/read each member manually.

Comment: Format your question properly and make use of correct spelling and grammar. If you don't put any effort in your question, don't expect strangers to care about your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data of the list (eh, `data`)  is not stored inside your class, but is allocated separately on the heap. It will not be stored in the file when you just dump a copy of the `ip_file_handler`.

You will have to write out each of the strings in the list separately, and recreate the list when reading them back in again.

Comment: Thank you Bo Persson, i will try this.